# CSS3 pseudo class with selectivizr in IE8 and below

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with styling my radio input if :checked with selectivizr. Can you please help me how to make it work with selectivizr. If there is another method how to do it please wirte below. here is link to my site: [test_radio_buttons](http://testinzerce.4fan.cz/test_radio/) and below is my CSS and HTML code ? Thank you all for your time and effort.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="checked-polyfill.js"></script>
     <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            $('input:radio').checkedPolyfill();
       });
     </script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Radio</title>

</head>

<body>

<form>
    <input type="radio" id="musi_se_jmenovat_stejne1" name="address" />
    <label for="musi_se_jmenovat_stejne1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="musi_se_jmenovat_stejne2" name="address" />
    <label for="musi_se_jmenovat_stejne2"></label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background: url('radio_un.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    background: url('radio_in.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type="radio"].checked + label{
    background: url('radio_in.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work for me (Windows 7)

Comment: How do you test it ? Maybe browserstack.com not support javascript dunno.

Comment: Browserstack and what browser version ?

Comment: U tested my website testinzerce.4fan.cz/test_radio ?

Comment: In browserstack my radiobuttons doesn't work maybe because I have 30mins trial access ?

Comment: Yes I used your website. [See](http://linenwoods.com/mathilde/test.png)

Comment: Man, I am so desperate now. I use same OS same browser as You, and my buttons doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please give me last reply if it works or not. Then I delete all my previous comments. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you make javascript work in browserstack, i tried fiddle example and it seems that javascript is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poly-fills like this one here: https://github.com/rdebeasi/checked-polyfill did work for me.
It adds a checked class in IE8 when the onchange event is triggered on the label.

I do remember to have had an issue with selectivizr and making this work.
See the fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5a7Gj/15/
Tested in IE8 on browser stack and it does not work with selectivr. It does not add any checked class.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    background: url('radio_in.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type="radio"].checked
{
    background: url('radio_in.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your post, where and how should i implement checked-polyfill.js in my code to make it work. Im noob. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your checked-polyfill and It doesn't work for me on browserstack.com.

Comment: You have to run the script $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input:checked').checkedPolyfill();
});

Comment: Yes I did but it doesn't work when i tested it on browserstack.com, maybe there is issue on their page, maybe in version of my jquery I use 1.4.3. F**k this old ie browser really.

Comment: where should I put this code inside if lt IE9 condition or after this condition, should i use $(document).ready function and put inside this code.

Comment: You have to run the script after the script and jquery is included 
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').checkedPolyfill();
});

Comment: I did as u write but without good result on browserstack.com when I test windows 7 and IE8. Firebug says 0 error in console. i think it is problem with browserstack.com.

Comment: Also add the label.checked styles seperately. IE8 does not recognize :checked and does not parse the .checked styles when they are together like input:checked +label, label.checked ...

Comment: wait a sec please i will edit my code on top u will see very easily what i did wrong. BTW thank you for everything.

Comment: $('input:radio').checkedPolyfill(); not $('input:checked').checkedPolyfill(); as u write before ?

Comment: I edited as u write, I think It should work now tried in browserstack.com without result. Can you tried it if it works. Thanks

Comment: After u write me if it works or not and why. I will delete all my comments and checked this answer.

Comment: Should work  $( document).ready(function() { $('input:radio').checkedPolyfill(); })(jQuery);